# checkboxes disappear on button click gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, webforms

I populated a gridview with a checkbox programatically like this :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)
  {
    e.Row.Cells[ColumnSelect].Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox());
 }
}
```

but when I click any button on the form the checkbox controls disappear before I can figure out which ones were clicked.  how can I save that info ?
thanks,
Diana

Comment: Try after putting this code in the Page_Load method: 
if(IsPostBack) { GridView1_RowDataBound(sender,e);}

Comment: Hi, that doesnt work, gives me this error: Error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs'

Comment: @Dianna Sorry I just noticed the second parameter of your function. You can take the help of The Solution's answer. Idea remains same that you have to build the controls in Load again.

Comment: in the on page load event the control has already disappeared so I cant tell if its been checked or not.  so how can I get this information.

Answer (score 1):

These controls need to be **recreated** every single time on `Load`. In short, dynamic controls in an ASP.NET application lose existence on a post back. You will want to create a `List<CheckBox>` that you store in `Session` and use that list to **rebuild** these controls in `Load`.

Comment: Hi Can you send me a link that explains how to do that in code? thanks

Comment: HELP , I am trying to store this in a list but the control disappears as soon as I hit the button it no longer exists in the onload method so how can I capture if its been checked or not!  there doesnt seem to be any moment once I click the button on which the control still exists.

Comment: I solved this by adding the checkbox as a template instead of programatically